# Display a local PDF file as view embedded inside a WebBrowser Control

Tags: powershell, pdf

I'm writing an PowerShell application which aim to **display a PDF file**. PDF can be display in some control e.g. WebBrowser. The PDF file will be located on the *disk*, not in the Internet.

I was trying to do it with WebBrowser Control and **Itext** Library, but it didn't work.

Tiny part of my code:

```
$WebBrowser.Navigate("C:\...\My_file.pdf")
$WebBrowser.Url = "C:\...\My_file.pdf"
```

Do you have any tips for me how to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to open a pdf, I would recommend you to use the `Start-Process` cmdlet to open the PDF using the *local standard* PDF reader:

```
Start-Process ((Resolve-Path "C:\..\My_file.pdf").Path)
```

Comment: Yes, I know this command, thank you. But I'm interested in displaying it in my Powershell program via some control, not open local PDF Reader. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for this!  I also tried a simpler version and found it worked.

    "Start-Process C:\..\My_file.pdf"

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to open a pdf file.  you could do something like:

```
& <path to program> <path to file>
```

ex:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\diskspaceauth-2017-05-08.pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks - maybe I can do a workaround based on your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I decided to covert a PDF file into a HTML. 
And then, display it by Webrowser. Worked like a charm:)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Invoke-Item` to [open pdf file from PowerShell](https://www.byteinthesky.com/powershell/open-pdf-file/).

```
Invoke-Item 'C:\Path\To\MyFile.pdf'
```